# Automation Anywhere - Can i run a bot on a machine if the Server or Control room is in the other place or location?

Tags: bots, rpa, automationanywhere

Is it possible to run a bot or task if the Server or Control Room is on the different location? for example the bots is in the building 1 and the server is in the building 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking if physical location of servers makes any differences on how BOTs works. The answer is No.